# Nullpointer in a strange place

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I can not understand how this could possibly throw a nullpointer exception. The code is as follows:

```
if (gameServers.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}
int freeSlots = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
GameServer chosenOne = null;
for (GameServer gs : gameServers) {
   if (gs.getSlots() > freeSlots) { // THIS LINE throws the nullpointer exception
       freeSlots = gs.getSlots();
       chosenOne = gs;
   }
}
```

Where `gs.getSlots()` is a simple `return this.slots`(of type int). The gameServers arraylist is filled with `new GameServer(..., ..., slots)` objects, those can't return null either.

Can anyone even tell me where to begin looking?

Comment: `gameServers` contains a `null` element. There is no other way you can get a NPE on that row.

Comment: What line does the null pointer happen on?

Comment: @Andrew_CS see the comment in the code

Comment: @Keppil That makes sense, but then I wonder how it got in there. I only add objects by `new GameServer(...)` and never remove any. It's not possible that any `new Obj()` returns null, is it?

Comment: Ah on phone, was off page.

Comment: Is `gameServers` perhaps an array, and you forgot to initialize the first/last element?

Comment: @Luc no, `new` never returns `null`. What is the rest of the code? Check all operations on `gameServers`

Comment: @Luc Is it possible that an Integer returned by `gs.getSlots()` is null and NPE is thrown in an unboxing attempt.

Comment: @Keppil It's an `ArrayList<GameServer>`. Might it be that, because gameservers are added via RMI, space is allocated in the ArrayList and set to null before the `new GS()` had a chance to finish and set the value? The GameServer constructor only sets some local variables, nothing that would take time.

Comment: Add debugging print that shows the values of gs?

Comment: Pavel is right. I don't think the `for` would iterate over `null` elements.

Comment: Use the debugger, so you can see exactly what happens.

Comment: @Paul Tried adding a debug message, and `gs` is indeed null. Now the question is why, hmm...

Comment: Which entry in the array? first, last, or no pattern to it?

Comment: @Arkain Good point, though I'm using a script to run 2 servers and 3 clients. Going through all steps, menus, logins and joins is kind of a pain. I'll keep it at system.outs for now.

Comment: @Arkain There's no magic `null` check in an enhanced `for` loop. If there's a null element in a list, it'll get iterated.

Comment: @Paul Alaways happens on the first element (well, 3/3 attempts), gameServers.size is 2.

Comment: @Luc, do you know it's the first element (only) or do you stop checking there because of the npe? Looks like the code of interest is where gameServers is modified, not used.

Comment: @Paul It stops checking at the first null element, so yeah the second might be null... But as this is for a demo tomorrow and I'll never look at the code again, I'm going to leave it at this and just check whether gs==null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if gs is null in your for loop, something like

```
if(gs != null && <insert original if statement>){
    ....
```

Comment: Adding a null check without understanding why it can be `null` is bad practice imo. It hides the actual issue without resolving it.

Comment: Yes the OP should find out why there is a null in collection, however in some apps he might not have access to that info.  Still should check to be safe.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Defensively checking for `null` everywhere just to be safe is a bad programming practice.

Comment: Once finding the null it would be up to OP to remove from the collection, raise an exception, etc.  I wouldn't allow it to crash the program if it wasn't something i could prevent on the other end.

Comment: Well much as I'd like to find out the root cause, I suppose this is going to be my workaround for the demo tomorrow. After tomorrow, if all goes well, the code will never be looked at again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Though your collection is not empty it may have a null element.

For eg

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add(null);
    if(!myList.isEmpty()) {
        for(String str : myList){
            System.out.println(str.length());
        }
    }
```

will throw an NPE. To avoid this you can have a simple null check.

```
    for (GameServer gs : gameServers) {
        if(gs != null) {
            if (gs.getSlots() > freeSlots) { 
                freeSlots = gs.getSlots();
                chosenOne = gs;
            }
        }
    }
```